# Why mmap still increase disk read?

Tags: linux, memory, linux-kernel, ubuntu-20.04

For Ubuntu 20.04, I use mmap map a disk file(about 4G).
The file changed by day, so I have to mmap another file day by day.
And I found sometimes(not always), the disk read increase fast although mmap done.
Why the mmap not load all the file to memory?

Answer (score 0):

In order to understand the problem, fistly you need to understand what happened if you call `mmap()`.

`mmap()` can be used to map virtual memory to physical memory, and it can also map file to own virtual memory. The function stack is like `ksys_mmap_pgoff()->vm_mmap_pgoff()->do_mmap_pgoff()->do_mmap()`. After this, we will construct the user space memory map, but it only apply a new area in the virtual memory, we haven't touched the physical memory. When processes schedule to this process and we want to address this physical memory, then it triggers page fault interrupt and call `do_page_fault()->find_vma()->handle_mm_fault()` to really get in touch with physical memory, for different file system we will use different function like `ext3_filemap_fault()`.

Now let's get back into the question.`mmap()` will cause disk read, but we cannot be sure when it will happen. It depends on when you used it and when CPU schedule to this process.

What's more, if you use `free` or other tools, you will find Linux OS have a design named `Buffer` and `Cache`.

```
buffers    Memory used by kernel buffers (Buffers in /proc/meminfo)
cache      Memory used by the page cache and slabs (Cached and SReclaimable in /proc/meminfo)
```

This mechanism will help to accelecrate I/O read/write speed, and it may also cause the disk read increase when you use `mmap()`.

Comment: So if I use mmap, then "free -h",  the physical memory used is shown by "buff/cache"

Comment: @DinoStray It's not the same thing